# Faulty 302 image causes entire page to redirect?

Tags: javascript, image, http-status-code-302, vast

I'm seeing a weird issue with an advertising product I'm working on: one of our partners has misimplemented one of their tracking pixels, which causes the request to `302 Redirect` to their homepage. Instead of this pixel not loading correctly or, you know, sane behavior, the entire page gets redirected when I insert this pixel into the page. Is this expected behavior? I'm trying to find specs that document this just so I'm aware of when this occurs and to figure out if there's a way to catch this.

Comment: Which server-side technology is being used ? any `http-interceptor` is implemented ?

Comment: @RayonDabre i have no idea, they're an external partner so we have no control over this. to clarify: this happens when inserting their pixel through javascript (`var img = new Image(); img.src = trackingUrl; document.body.appendChild(img);`)

Comment: Show us the URL of their image that causes that redirect and the HTML that you are using to display the image.